# RmiProxyFactoryBean timeout

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I'm using Spring RMI in order to communicate from client to server. Here is the configuration

```
<bean id="remoteNotifier" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://localhost:10101/rmi-notifier"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="org.my.package.SyncNotifyExposed"/>
    <property name="refreshStubOnConnectFailure" value="true" />
</bean>
```

My question is:
How can I configure client timeout? So the client will wait let's say only 30seconds to response?

Thanks

Comment: Have you googled `RmiProxyFactoryBean timeout site:stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: I saw this onehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521708/spring-3-0-rmiproxyfactorybean-how-to-set-connection-timeout but it didn't really help

Comment: I'm not good on sockets but the code in the question looks plausible(OP updated it), see for example [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1822760/241986) - it seems to be inspired by the latter answer.

Comment: The code in that answer is fifteen years out of date and applies to RMI/JRMP only. Does Spring RMI really use that?

Answer (score 0):

#### tomcat config:

go to vmoptions

```
set -Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout=30000 (milliseconds)
```

---

#### websphere config:

go to Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine

```
set -Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout=30000 in Generic JVM arguments section
```